# why are images not found after Response.Redirect?

Tags: asp.net

I have a parts.aspx page that displays correctly when user navigates to it from the menu. I also have code behind another  page that redirects to to parts.aspx and when that happens everything works except the images on parts.aspx do not display, just the alternate text. The images are in an Images subfolder of the folder containing parts.aspx. So why are the images files not located? using asp 2.0, VS 2005.

Comment: can you show some HTML for one of the images on the parts.aspx page? as well as the code for the Redirect.

Comment: Yeah, please show us some codes to get clearly answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing Server.Transfer instead of Response.Redirect then the relative paths you have entered in parts.aspx may no longer be correct based on the URL you are at. You didn't actually say that was your issue, but it sounds like it to me.

You should probably post some of your code to get better answers.